# Making a different value the default using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the default value different than what is defined in the HTML. I cannot change the HTML because it is locked by a parent company of ours. I can however change the default if I use javascript. Here is the HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="addressTypeWrapper" class="form-group">
        <label for="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString">Type</label>
        <select name="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString" id="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString" class="form-control" required >          
     <option value="Home" selected="selected">Home</option>
     <option value="Office">Office</option>
     <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
     <option value="Other">Other</option>
     <option value="Billing">Billing</option>
     <option value="Purchaser">Purchaser</option>
     <option value="Foreign">Foreign</option>
     <option value="Agency">Agency</option>
     <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
     <option value="School">School</option>
     <option value="Campus">Campus</option>
     <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
     <option value="Shipping">Shipping</option>
     <option value="Local">Local</option>
     <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option></select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now how would I make the Office value the default only using javascript?

Comment: Remove the `selected` attribute (use `removeAttribute()`) from the current option, and add it (use `setAttribute()`) to the option you need to. This way the wanted option really becomes the default value (even after `form.reset()`).

Comment: Could you show me what the removeattribute would look like for this, because I am trying this and it is not working. Thanks!

Comment: [Here ...](http://jsfiddle.net/k4skb7b9/1/). Notice, that you can run the script _after_ the `select` element has been parsed to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I appreciate the help, I am new to javascript and haven't had to use it that much yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use that one line of javascript below to change the value on runtime

```js
document.getElementById('addressListArray[0].addressTypeString').value = 'Office';
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="addressTypeWrapper" class="form-group">
        <label for="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString">Type</label>
        <select name="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString" id="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString" class="form-control" required >          
     <option value="Home" selected="selected">Home</option>
     <option value="Office">Office</option>
     <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
     <option value="Other">Other</option>
     <option value="Billing">Billing</option>
     <option value="Purchaser">Purchaser</option>
     <option value="Foreign">Foreign</option>
     <option value="Agency">Agency</option>
     <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
     <option value="School">School</option>
     <option value="Campus">Campus</option>
     <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
     <option value="Shipping">Shipping</option>
     <option value="Local">Local</option>
     <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option></select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
!function(){var e=document.getElementsByTagName("option");e[0].selected=!1,e[1].selected=!0}();
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="addressTypeWrapper" class="form-group">
        <label for="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString">Type</label>
        <select name="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString" id="addressListArray[0].addressTypeString" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="Home" selected="selected">Home</option>
            <option value="Office">Office</option>
            <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            <option value="Billing">Billing</option>
            <option value="Purchaser">Purchaser</option>
            <option value="Foreign">Foreign</option>
            <option value="Agency">Agency</option>
            <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
            <option value="School">School</option>
            <option value="Campus">Campus</option>
            <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
            <option value="Shipping">Shipping</option>
            <option value="Local">Local</option>
            <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the dropdown and use `.val()`. If its a dynamic `id` then add another attribute like `data-dropdown="list"` as I have done below

`$("select[data-dropdown='list']").val('Office');`